# AACDecoder turn up the volume of player?

Tags: android

I'm using AACDecoder to listen stream. Here the site: https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/ . Now I'm looking for how could I turn up the volume of player. I'm using MultiPlayer to listen.

How could I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved your problem and need any answer but I found a solution and want to share it.

Please review [`AudioTrack`.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html)

You can get AudioTrack using player callback after MultiPlayer started playing your url. `com.spoledge.aacdecoder.PlayerCallback.playerAudioTrackCreated(AudioTrack audioTrack)`

When you want to set volume, use [`AudioTrack.setStereoVolume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#setStereoVolume(float,%20float)) or [`AudioTrack.setVolume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#setVolume(float)) method.